# Package.json in MVC template with VSCode

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-code

I imported MVC template by running `dotnet new mvc -lang C#`. I got default template here but I noticed it's missing `package.json` file.

How can I add `package.json` in VSCode editor to this template to add other required references ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **npm init** command from node package manager.

1. Open Nodejs command prompt.
2. Navigate to project directory.
3. type `npm init` command.
4. Specify basic details like name, version, description, entry point etc.

This will create basic of `package.json`. Then, you can use `npm install <package> --save` to install new npm packages in your project.

Other option is, you can create package.json manually.

Comment: thanks . 
can you suggest some link where i can find good staff to grasp asp.net core with vscode?.On official side of microsoft ,they have well described fundamentals but project point of view ,they jumped with vs2017.

Comment: I am not aware of any tutorial site for asp.net core with vscode. With VScode, you will have to use cli commands from official docs. I would recommend you to use VS2017. Community version is available for developers.